# Как сделать так,чтобы при слайде основная фотография уменьшалась?

Tags: html, css, jquery

Главная страница, а когда слайдишь - основная фотография уменьшается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понятна цель, но попробуйте обратить внимание на cycle плагин jquery. Реализация слайдера с довольно обширным функционалом и простым API. Может найдете решение там. Прикрепляю ссылку, можете там демо как раз посмотреть
https://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=400